How to programmatically filter out the IP addresses from a VM?
I have this piece of code to retrieve the ethernet IP address:
public static IPAddress GetEthernetIpAddress()
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        return ip.Address;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return default;
}

However, if a VM is installed, it can return that VM's IP address. How to filter out VM IP addresses?
One solution I found online suggests checking whether there is a gateway address because apparently a VM network interface won't have one, but Googling to confirm this gave me a different answer:
if (ni.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault() == null)

ChatGPT o1-preview suggested checking the network interface name against "vEthernet", but I don't trust that method (don't mind that StringComparison parameter):
if (!ni.Name.Contains("vEthernet", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

I haven't found anything useful in the official documentation for NetworkInterface or UnicastIPAddressInformation. Any idea?

I do not think this is possible. First of all it will depend on how the virtualization software handles the network. Second, the point of virtual machines is to make them transparent to software, trying to filter out VMs could lead to all sorts of problems. I would suggest letting the user configure this.

What exactly are you trying to achieve, why do you need to know the IP address of the actual ethernet interface? Note a system may have multiple interfaces: I have a server with five different physical interfaces and three more virtual interfaces, some of which have multiple IP addresses on different subnets, and all interfaces are active.

@Charlieface My client requires our software to be able to connect to medical devices as a server. Hence displaying their IP to help configure the medical devices to connect to our software.

So I'm still not sure what you are asking. If you are running inside a VM then it only has one interface usually anyway, that is your only link to the outside world. Otherwise you could have multiple interface. The only definitive way is to tell which is the one that goes to the outside world is maybe to check the route table to find out which one has the default route prefix 0.0.0.0/0 see eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netroute?view=windowsserver2022-ps where you can do this from Powershell

For example Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 | Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex {$_.InterfaceIndex} -AddressFamily IPv4 in Powershell would get you the IPv4 address of the interface which holds the default route. You can use Powershell.Create from C# to call PS directly.
